# What is the limit of this sequence of complex numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be two complex numbers in the upper half-plane.

Does the sequence $c_n = \exp^n\left(\sqrt{\log^n(z_1) \cdot \log^n(z_2)}\right)$ converge to a fixed point as $n\to\infty$? If so, what is the value of this fixed point for a given $z_1$ and $z_2$?

(The square root and complex logarithm are assumed to have the conventional branch cuts running from $-\infty$ to $0$.)

EDIT: The $\exp^n$ and $\log^n$ above are meant to be iterates of the respective functions. That is, $\log^n(x)=\log(\log^{n-1}(x))$ .

Comment: These are $n$th powers, or $n$th iterates, of the functions?

Comment: Thanks for the question @GregMartin, they're meant to be iterates. I edited the problem statement to clarify.

Comment: Setting the scene: Numerical experiments suggest that the iterates of $\log$ converge to the constant value $z_0 = 0.318131510242323822656215705231 + 1.337235702547544640733984733034i$, which satisfies $\log z_0 = z_0 = \exp z_0$. Taking each further iterate of log near this point shrinks the distance to $z_0$ by a factor of $1/|z_0|$. Of course, taking each further iterate of exp nearby grows the distance by $|z_0|$. So the two effects balance out? suggesting convergence, but indeed to some value depending on $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Comment: What is a source of this problem?

Comment: @Did No source per se--just a problem I haven't been able to solve.

Comment: But you *made* the problem yourself? Why this one?